# Loading control data externally

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have controls which load data from an external service. This works fine but the control is either void of any data or full of data.

How would I implement adding extra modes to those controls for "loading" and "error loading" (or something to that effect)

I know I can probably use OnPropertyChange to tell whether the data has changed, how do I pick up that a download has failed.

At the moment I do something like this

```
wc.OpenReadCompleted += Feed;
wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(formattedFeedUrl));

...

private void Feed(object Sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        return; // here I want to notify that there's a download error somehow to the usercontrol
    }
    using (Stream s = e.Result)
    {
        // here I populate the ObservableCollection and notifychange

        // and somewhere here, if the xml does not generate any data i want to notify a control also.
```

Is there any technique I can use to display a loading/error notice instead of an unpopulated control, if there were a ServiceControl rather than a simple usercontrol which had 3 states that would work. Is there a way to control states based on the binding?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could achieve what you are asking for.

1. The simple solution would be to just have multiple layers in a Grid element and switch their visibilities depending on the logical state of your control.
2. Another way would be to have a ViewModel that has a state property and either a set of Visibility type properties that are bound to the different layers and are updated every time your logical state changes or
3. bind the state property directly to the visibilities of these layers and have a converter that returns the right visibility to the  layer corresponding to the state of the control.
4. Finally, you could use the VisualStateManager to control the state of the control.
5. Additionally - you could use DataTemplates or directly build and update the contents of your UI in code behind.

It all depends on what your know, what you prefer and where you want to go with your code. If this is a one-off solution for your application - I would use a ViewModel with some Visibility properties, since I personally prefer to do things using the MVVM pattern. If what you want to have is a reusable control, then you could set the visibilities in the code behind as the simplest solution or use the VisualStateManager as the most fancy one.

Another thing that comes to mind now is to have an attached dependency property or a Behavior that you bind to the state of your control and it automatically overlays your control with some sort of a progress indicator, so you could reuse that adp/behavior for different controls.